# Unable to increase memory pool of Tomcat7

Tags: java, tomcat, solr, tomcat7, windows-server-2012

I am trying to update memory pool size in Tomcat configuration on Windows Server 2012. But after configure the memory size limits, if I restart the Tomcat server I am not able to do it. After revert the changes it started again and works fine.

I am configuring following details:

Tomcat Configuration Block ->Go to the Java tab. At the bottom, below the "Java Options" textarea, you will find 3 input fields:

Initial memory pool ____MB
Maximum memory pool ___ MB
Thread stack size _____ KB

I am able to save changes in this tab, but when I tried to restart Tomcat I can not. But when I revert the changes I made, it start working again.

Please let me know what I have to do in such case.

Thank You.

Comment: What are you not able to do, start tomcat, change the pool size? How are you exactly changing the memory setting.

Comment: What values did you set for them? You were not able to restart the server after changing the values?

Comment: I have set initial memory pool to 1024 MB and Maximum memory pool to 2048 MB. And yes after save this changes I am not able to restart it. If I hit start button then process is not being started.

Comment: Actually I am facing an error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space and that's why I am changing this value.